# ratchet PHP Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, websocket

I trying to connect ratchet with `mysql` database but I get this erorr 
I run mysql using xampp phpmyadmin and I used the code in connectToDB.php file before to send data from html form to sql row using php and that worked ok 
and I tested the code in `Chat.php` file before I adding the sql lines and that was working good but after I added the connectToDB.php line in chat.php i get this error so where the proplem ?
the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND'
>   in htdocs/connectToDB.php on line 19

the `connectToDB.php` code

```
<?php
if(!session_id()) session_start();



/* $dbhost  = 'localhost';
//$dbname       = '1852132_ch';
//$dbuser       = 'root';
//$dbpass       = ''; */

$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "test";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "";

// database connection
try{
    $_db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass, array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8", 
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
                )); 
}catch(Excepion $e){
    die("ERROR : ".$e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

the `Chat.php` file code

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;

include('/opt/lampp/htdocs/ww/classes/user.php');
include('/opt/lampp/htdocs/ww/connectToDB.php');

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
        $sql = $_db->query("UPDATE users SET userid= '1999' WHERE UserName='batman'");

    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php.ini file, you should have the following line (uncommented):

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll on Windows
extension=php_pdo_mysql.so on Linux/Mac
```

Then restart apache and try your code

Comment: @rafid in any section ? there are sections like [pdo],[pcre],etc..
in any one of them i should add it ?

Comment: Go to xampp control panel and click `config` button and open` php.ini` file and search `php_pdo_mysql` and remove `;` before `php_pdo_mysql`  and save. Then restart apache and try your code